# AWS IOS SDK 1.7.0 -> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, amazon-s3, linker-errors

I'm trying to use the amazon AWS for iOS SDK but I keep getting several `Apple Mach-O Linker errors` in Xcode 5.0.1

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3CreateBucketRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3Region", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonEndpoints", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreationViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonS3Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreationViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I went into the build phases and made sure the `AWSES.framework` is included in `link binary with libraries`. In the compile sources CreationViewController.m is also included.
Target Memberships also seem to be correct. What else can I do?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?, I am having the same issue. I even downloaded the new sdk.

Comment: Are you sure you've imported the correct header files for the service you want to use? If you're using S3 be sure you've included the following header files.
`#import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>` and not <AWSSES/AWSSES.h> (which was my issue)

Comment: i am building it for iPhone 5s 64 bit, and the compiler says the following
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonEndpoints", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CreateProfileController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AmazonS3Client", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AwsUploadEngine.o
      objc-class-ref in CreateProfileController.o
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_S3PutObjectRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AwsUploadEngine.o

Comment: In the build phases tab of xcode. are the AWSS3 frameworks and AWSRuntime frameworks visible in the "link with libraries" section? are the target memberships correct?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My solution was to delete the AWSRuntime.framework and the AWSS3.framework from the project. I then went back to the Amazon site to re-download the aws-ios-sdk-1.6.1. Using the Build Phase -> Link Binary Libraries (+) button I added the fresh frameworks back to the Xcode project and it ran with no problems. I had moved the project from  Dropbox to a loaner and back again via Dropbox after my hard drive died. My guess is that this  corrupted the files or Amazon has something in the code that frowns on copping the it from one place to another rather than getting it straight from them.

Comment: Absolutely confirm. Had the same identical issue and this resolved it for me. Thanks a ton!